# Distinguish between Exception and Failure in a CATCH block [ RAKU ]

Tags: exception, try-catch, raku

We know that a Failure can be handled by a CATCH block.

In the following example we create an 'AdHoc' Failure (in other-sub) and we handle the Exception in a CATCH block (in my-sub)

```
sub my-sub {
    try {
        CATCH {
            when X::AdHoc { say 'AdHoc Exception handled here'; .resume }
            default {say 'Other Exception'; .resume}
        }

        my $b = other-sub();

        $b.so ?? $b.say !! 'This was a Failure'.say;
    }
}

sub other-sub { fail 'Failure_X' }

my-sub();
```

The output is the following:

```
AdHoc Exception handled here
This was a Failure
```

My question is though: How can we distinguish between Failure and a "normal" Exception in the CATCH block in order to differentiate between the two cases?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The relationship between `Failure` and `Exception` is that a `Failure` has an `Exception` - that is to say, it holds the exception object as part of its state. Something like this:

```
class Failure {
    has Exception $.exception;
    # ...
}
```

When a `Failure` "explodes", it does so by throwing the `Exception` that is inside of it. Thus, what reaches the `CATCH` block is the `Exception` object, and there's no link back to the enclosing `Failure`. (In fact, a given `Exception` object could in principle be held by many `Failure`s.)

Therefore, there's no direct way to detect this. From a design perspective, you probably shouldn't be, and should find a different way to solve your problem. A `Failure` is just a way to defer the throwing of an exception and allowing for it to be treated as a value; it's not intended that the nature of the underlying problem changes because it's conveyed as a value rather than as an immediate transfer of control flow. Unfortunately, the original goal wasn't stated in the question; you may find it useful to look at control exceptions, but otherwise perhaps post another question about the underlying problem you're trying to solve. There's probably a better way.

For completeness, I'll note that there *are* indirect ways that one may detect that the `Exception` was thrown by a `Failure`. For example, if you obtain the `.backtrace` of the exception object and look at the top frame's package, it's possible to determine that it comes from the `Failure`:

```
sub foo() { fail X::AdHoc.new(message => "foo") }
try {
    foo();
    CATCH {
        note do { no fatal; .backtrace[0].code.package ~~ Failure };
        .resume
    }
}
```

However, this is heavily dependent on implementation details that could easily change, so I'd not rely on it.

Comment: Just to clarify things up, my intension is to handle only for exceptions (in the CATCH block). In case of a Failure i want to resume as if nothing happened and let the rest of the code (outside of CATCH) handle the Failure.

In my example I didn't expect the returned Failure to trigger the contained Exception! All I did is getting the result in $b and checking it as a Bool. That, in my view, doesn't constitute "use" of the Failure and therefore triggering of the CATCH block!

Instead of that it seems that the CATCH is always handling the Exception contained in the Failure!!

Comment: Furthermore in your example, about the indirect way of detecting a Failure, the returned Bool (from smart checking the Failure Type) is of value "False". But I expected it to be "True"! Did I miss something???

Comment: @jakar A `try` block implies the `use fatal` pragma, which means any `Failure` returned from a call made in the block is immediately converted into an exception. Just don't use `try`; a `CATCH` can go in any block in Raku (so just have it at the level of the `sub`). Alternatively, write `no fatal` at the top of your `try` block.

Comment: And what about my second comment?

Comment: Running the example I gave prints `True` on the Rakudo version I have locally. If it doesn't on yours, that just proves the point about the fragility of doing this.

Comment: Thought the same but needed your confirmation anyways!

Answer (score 7):

Just remove the `try` wrapper:

```
sub my-sub {

#    try {              <--- remove this line...

        CATCH {
            when X::AdHoc { say 'AdHoc Exception handled here'; .resume }
            default {say 'Other Exception'; .resume}
        }

        my $b = other-sub();

        $b.so ?? $b.say !! 'This was a Failure'.say;

#    }                  <--- ...and this one

}

sub other-sub { fail 'Failure_X' }

my-sub();
```

You used `try`. A `try` does a few things, but the pertinent thing here is that it tells Raku to immediately promote any `Failure`s in its scope to exceptions -- which is what you say you *don't* want. So the simplest solution is to just stop doing that.

---

This answer just verbosely repeats part of jnthn's explanation (see in particular comments he wrote below his answer). But I wasn't convinced all readers would spot/understand this aspect, and didn't think a comment or two on jnthn's answer would help, hence this answer.

I've written this as a community answer to ensure I won't benefit from any upvotes because it obviously doesn't warrant that. If it gets enough downvotes we'll just delete it.